# How to show result in html forms using API (PHP)

Tags: php, html, jquery, rest

I have my sample html to fetch data from my API and show in the form fields.
I want first to fetch the data using an API then and save into my localhost application. Is this possible?

Type Employee ID: 10005

I've modified the script and it works but there some strings needs to replace.

```js
function callREST() {
            event.preventDefault(); //for demo to prevent form submit.
            var inputZip = document.getElementById("empID").value;
            var url = 'https://sancarloscityhospital.com/api/read.php?id=' + inputZip;
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                    //document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    // document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = this['register_user_id'].responseText;
                    var arr = this.responseText.split(',');
            
                    $("#empId").val(arr[2].replace(/user_empId|"|:/g, ""));
                    $("#empName").val(arr[3]);
                    $("#empEmail").val(arr[4]);
                   
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
```

```html
<form action="#">
       
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="empID">Enter Employee ID</label>
            <input type="text" id="empID">
        </div>
        <div class="button-holder">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="callREST();">Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    
     <form action="">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Employee ID</label>
            <input type="text"  id="empId">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Employee Name</label>
            <input type="text"  id="empName">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Email</label>
            <input type="email"  id="empEmail">
        </div>
    </form>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

result like this one:

```html
<form action="">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Employee ID</label>
        <input type="text" value="10005">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Employee Name</label>
        <input type="text" value="Bill Pabalate">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Email</label>
        <input type="ecmail" value="billpabs@gmail.com">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: And what is a localhost application?

Comment: If you want to save some kind of data to the client's browser, simply use cookies.

Comment: It works now but there are some values need to replace the strings like in email and employee name.